# Using this if it exists / Detecting calling convention of current scope in C++ (thiscall vs cdecl)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a robust macro that will work within both thiscall and cdecl calling conventions, but to utilize 'this' for additional information if 'this' exists (thiscall).

Is it possible?

Here's an example that does not work:

```
#define PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS \
   if (this) printf("this (addr %08x) exists in %s!\n", size_t(this), __FUNCTION__)

struct MyStruct
{
   void MyFunc()
   {
      PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS;
   }
};

void StaticFunc()
{
   PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS;
   MyStruct ms;
   ms.MyFunc();
}
```

Desired runtime output:

> this (addr 0015f330) exists in MyStruct::MyFunc!

Observed compiler error:

> Example.cpp(14): error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions

I'm using clang and Visual Studio, and getting it to work in either individually is still useful.  This seems similar to SFINAE, but I didn't find anything related to just 'this'

Comment: A variable argument member function (`void func(...);`) will hose that up real quickly.

Comment: What would be the purpose of calling that macro in a static function?

Comment: @EboMike consider one's own definition of ASSERT, if it could access this it could automatically report information.  Pretty powerful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You might come up with something nicer but this just might work.
Tested in MSVC++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS \
    if (strchr(__FUNCTION__,':')) printf("this exists in %s!\n", __FUNCTION__)

class test
{
public:
    test()
    {
        PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS;
    }
};

void staticFunction()
{
    PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS;
}

int main()
{
    PRINT_IF_THIS_EXISTS;
    staticFunction();
    test t;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear, I then want to reference this in some manner, not to just know that it's in a thiscall.  I'll adjust the question to reflect that.

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean by "I then want to reference this" but what you are trying to do looks kind of impossible. The this pointer simply points to the class and is accessible only within the nonstatic member functions of a class, struct, or union type. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx

Comment: Well, that's why I asked if it was possible.  I've seen some pretty crazy things be possible with SFINAE though.  If the existence of functions and members can be tested and operated on conditional to their existence, then why not this?

Comment: well you might come up with another solution, but trying to tackle the issue with focusing too much on the this pointer might not get you there since you simply can't use it outside of a class etc.

Answer (score 0):

`is_foo_static` in following code checks if `X::foo()` is a static function.
Maybe you can use it in your macro to tell if it is thiscall.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_foo_static {
  template<typename X>
  static std::true_type check(X*, decltype(X::foo())* = 0);

  static std::false_type check(...);
  typedef decltype(check((T*)(0))) _tmp;
  static const bool value = _tmp::value;
};

struct FooStatic {
  static void foo() {}
};

struct FooNonStatic {
  void foo() {}
};

int main(){
  cout<<boolalpha
      <<is_foo_static<FooStatic>::value<<endl
      <<is_foo_static<FooNonStatic>::value<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```